# How can I add total number of rows (dynamically)?

Tags: angular, html-table, primeng

This is the code that I have for Angular and PrimeNG P-table:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="questions" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedQuestion"  [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,15,20,50,1000]" [rows]="15" [responsive]="true" [autoLayout]="true"
        sortMode="multiple">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                    {{col.header}}
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft">
            Showing {{dataTable?.dataToRender?.length}} rows
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

I want to add a total number of rows on the left side of pagination portion so that when e.g. use some filter - number of rows decreases automatically.

In the middle of a code snippet above - I tried to add that feature but is not working (number is not showing). Anyone has working example?

Comment: I am kinda confused, so here you have the row data to be shown as rowData but for the number of rows - we are trying to take it from the dataTable?.dataToRender?length??

Comment: @Jay had the same questions. where is even dataTable coming from.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state>
  {{state.rows}}
</ng-template>
```

- state: $implicit state.page: Current page
- state.rows: Rows per page
- state.first: Index of the first records
- state.totalRecords: Number of total records

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6he3b2 Look under the provider search html

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Comment: Thanks, I tried with this and `state.totalRecords` and is close but not perfect yet.. If there are e.g. 10 pages and each page has 15 records - expected to see total of 150 records. However - it is showing 15 (total record for that first page).

Comment: .rows shows the number of rows you have assigned to show per page (at the top of you table [rows]="15", and totalRecord the total number of records on your entire table. Unfortunately there's nothing exactly to what you want made by primeng. You will have to build it yourself

Comment: @Joe see comment above

Comment: Thanks. I tried with `state.totalRecords` and weird thing first time it shows 0. If I click on 'page 2' it updates the number from 0 to e.g. 83 (total number of records in a table). Wondering if this is a glitch in library or I need to `activate` it somehow during the 'first pass'.

Comment: @Joe uhmmm that's weird. Did you see my updated answer. I have a working stackbliz there and it should soe total number of record from the beginning not need to trigger anything

Comment: Hmm.. I put `{{state.totalRecords}}` in your code in stackbliz and is showing Total number of records first time.. I will compare with my code.. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe please do it weird the issue you are having. If you need more help let me know. Hope I can assist you the best I can

Answer (score 2):

Hoping someone finds this useful:

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state>
        Showing {{(state.page  * state.rows) + 1}} to {{state.rows * (state.page + 1)}} of {{state.totalRecords}}
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Gives:

[image]